# TypeError: Textbox.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'info' - This error comes when launching Stable Diffusion

Tags: stable-diffusion

```
 File "F:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\routes.py", line 422, in run_predict
    output = await app.get_blocks().process_api(
  File "F:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1326, in process_api
    data = self.postprocess_data(fn_index, result["prediction"], state)
  File "F:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 1251, in postprocess_data
    prediction_value = postprocess_update_dict(
  File "F:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 423, in postprocess_update_dict
    update_dict = block.get_specific_update(update_dict)
  File "F:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\gradio\blocks.py", line 308, in get_specific_update
    specific_update = cls.update(**generic_update)
TypeError: Textbox.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'info'
```

Not sure what to do.

Comment: is there a cmd line that I can use to reinstall? or way to check which version of Gradio I have

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you did, and I resolved it by making some code changes. This is a bug in the 'gradio' library, and the latest version should have fixed it. You can find the pull request related to this issue here: `https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/pull/4715/files#diff-67385871d553144fb7c5ea0fd0aca8b52b3a8575cb15a13715661eb8264c657aR147-R162`. If you choose not to update to the latest version, you can manually fix the code based on the changes in the pull request.

P.S.: You can check the current version of Gradio by running 'pip list'.